# Restangular add custom method

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

How can I add a custom method to Restangular?

I have:

```
RestangularProvider.addElementTransformer('names', false, function(name) {

        agravo.addRestangularMethod('light', 'get', 'light');

        return name;
    });
```

And I want the request like:

```
{url}/names/light
```

The light URL need to return a list.

Comment: If you want a request to that url `{url}/names/list` you can use `Restangular.all('names').all('light').getList()` why do you need custom?

Comment: A have a NameService that returns Restangular.service('names'); and I desire to put light method in service to call NameService.light();